# Find three numbers given their sum, product and sum of their squares

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, sums-of-squares

Given three unknown positive integers. Is it possible to find the three numbers if we are given their 
Sum->(a+b+c) = X
Product-> (abc) = Y
Sum of Squares-> (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) = Z

Answer (score 5):

Here is a method you can try. Let

$s_1=a+b+c$,

$s_2=a^2+b^2+c^2$,

$p_2=ab+bc+ac$,

$p_3=abc$

$a, b, c$ are the roots of the cubic $$0=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-s_1x^2+p_2x-p_3$$

We don't know $p_2$ but can calculate it using $s_1^2=s_2+2p_2$, and then solve the cubic to find $a,b,c$.

Comment: Is there an easy method to calculate the roots if coefficients are integers..?? Or any method other than Hit-and-Trial.

Comment: @user143544 You need to find three different numbers, and one of the conditions you have fixes the third degree expression $abc$. So you almost inevitably have to solve a cubic (special cases excepted). Integer solutions are constrained (if coefficients are integers they must be factors of $p_3$). There are formulae and methods for solving the general cubic - e.g. Cardano method http://mathsa.ucd.ie/courses/mst3022/history4.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Try squaring $X=(a+b+c)$.

Comment: when is the product used ?

Comment: but then how to get 2(ab+bc+ca)..??

Comment: It appears that I made a mistake whilst calculating as usual. Mark's method is best I can think of right now